# JOIN only if boolean is true

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, query-optimization

Is there a way to hint to Postgres that it should only attempt to do a JOIN lookup if `in_table_b` is set? This is purely a performance optimization and would not change the results.

```
Table A:
  id Serial
  in_table_b Boolean

Table B:
  id Int (Foreign Key A.id)
  foobar Text
```

Current query:

```
SELECT A.id, A.in_table_b, B.foobar FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = B.id;
```

I'd like a clause that effectively says: do not try to do an index lookup on B if `in_table_b` is false. However, I do want to return rows in A even if there is no matching row in B.

Comment: I doubt a boolean will affect the performance in this case.

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I don't get it: if there is no lookup of `b`, where should the value of `foobar` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really (and, in general, shouldn't try to) control *how* the database executes the query. SQL is a *descriptive* language: you tell the database the results that you want, and trust it to make the best decision in terms of execution plan - database designers put lot of effort into building engines that figure out the best possible strategy.

I would just add another condition to the `on` clause of the `left join`; this is the simplest way to express what you want:

```
select a.id, a.in_table_b, b.foobar 
from a 
left join b on a.id = b.id and a.in_table_b;
```

I would recommend an index on `a(in_table_b, id)`: this might somehow hint the query planner on how to proceed (the ordering of columns in the index is important here). However, it might also consider that a boolean column is not a very good pick, because the cardinality is not good (there are only two possible values). The database might still go for the index lookup - and actually, this could very well be the most efficient option.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that it's a LEFT JOIN. So I'd still want to see results where only the row in table A exists.

Comment: Also if you haven't done so yet, remember to add the index on the FK as in `Table B (id)`.

Comment: @GMB Why is the index on `in_table_b` important? I fully expect to have every row in `A` returned, but only some with additional data from `B`. The use of `in_table_b` in the JOIN clause is interesting, I'll give that a try.